# How to fix the peer dependencies Installation problem

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules, npm-install

I am trying to Install the react-contenteditable using npm.But peer dependencies of eslint are not allowing me to install with arisal of following Error. 
I am Using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS OS.

This is the code I have Used to install the react-contenteditable.

```
npm i react-contenteditable
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.11.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/experimental-utils@1.11.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@1.11.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@4.0.1 requires a peer of eslint@5.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-loader@2.1.2 requires a peer of eslint@>=1.6.0 <6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-import@2.16.0 requires a peer of eslint@2.x - 5.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@6.2.1 requires a peer of eslint@^3 || ^4 || ^5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@7.12.4 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-hooks@1.6.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.1.2 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.14.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.0.6 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.0.6: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ react-contenteditable@3.2.6
updated 1 package and audited 901320 packages in 20.608s
found 12 high severity vulnerabilities run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

I even tried the `npm audit fix` command but, It doesn't help me either.

Comment: It's showing in the logs that you have installed the package. Yeah there are some warnings that wont harm you much!

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know they are harmless. But if you are really absolutely annoyed with them, losing sleep, or making you showers unclean  you can try theese:

**Install typescript and eslint:**

```sh
npm install typescript
npm install eslint
```

This is for appeasing these warnings

```sh
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.11.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/experimental-utils@1.11.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@1.11.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@4.0.1 requires a peer of eslint@5.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-loader@2.1.2 requires a peer of eslint@>=1.6.0 <6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-import@2.16.0 requires a peer of eslint@2.x - 5.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@6.2.1 requires a peer of eslint@^3 || ^4 || ^5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@7.12.4 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-hooks@1.6.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.1.2 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.14.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

**npm force install**
I suggest you to not do this often if you don't have any problem. But this might be a good case.

```sh
npm install -f
```

This command is to placate these warnings:

```sh
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.0.6 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.0.6: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

---

Again ***they are harmless*** and you can try to live with them. Or you can try the commands above to have some small relief in life

Answer (score 3):

I understand this is a few months old but I thought I'd contribute my solution. It turned out for me that a particular version of typescript was looking for an older version of eslint. I used the [npm-update-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-update-all) global tool to bring all my packages up to date. The typescript updated to 3.6.4 and all the peer warnings went away. Of course you want to use a drastic measure like updating everything with discretion.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens even if everything has valid versions (peer dependencies). In such cases try this

```bash
rm -rf **/node_modules
rm -rf **/package-lock.json
```