# unable to install vue chart.js in vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-chartjs

I'm trying to install vue-chart.js but unable to install. I tried by reinstalling npm and deleting package-lock.json file but doesnot work. I tried other methods as well but couldnot get succeed.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You must install the dependencies given in error. Listed below:

> eslint@^5.0.0

For global install, use

```
npm install -g eslint
```

or For developement installation

```
npm install eslint --save-dev
```

Refer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint

Comment: I installed eslint but still I got above error. I updated image in question. @Guryash Singh

Comment: Have you installed **vue-chartjs**
`npm install vue-chartjs chart.js --save`
Refer
[https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#introduction]

Comment: yes I installed vue-chart.js but got above error. @Guryash Singh

Comment: Now I got "npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\xampp\htdocs\test\node_modules\vue-chartjs' -> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\bps-frontend\node_modules\.vue-chartjs.DELETE'

Comment: Refer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56738226/how-to-fix-the-peer-dependencies-installation-problem]

Comment: Reinstall **typescript & eslint**

Answer (score 0):

After deleting node modules and reinstalling npm solved my issue.